# Access control / creating new folder in ADLS

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am currently assigned to a contributor role, but I am getting Access control exception error when I try to access Data explorer and create a new folder ( there are currently no folders in Azure Data lake store).
What kind of permission do I need ? DO I have to be owner in order to create a new folder under root?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that explains it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control

See the section titled "Common scenarios related to permissions". Permissions needed to create a folder are same as those needed to delete a file in the folder.

For the parent folder , the caller needs Write + Execute permissions: (in this case this is the root)
For all the other folders in the file’s path, the caller needs Execute permissions. : (this doesn't apply if you're doing the operation at the root)